# XCode doesn't recognize variable ProfileHandler with pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

guys,

I have this pod file from a not too old project

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use 
dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for MyApp
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 7.0'
pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 7.0'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'RSKImageCropper'
pod 'Koloda', :git => 'https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda.git', :branch => 'swift-3'
pod 'MBAutoGrowingTextView'
pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'
pod 'SDAVAssetExportSession', :git => 'https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession.git'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

target 'MyAppTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
end

target 'MyAppUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

end
```

and when I run

```
pod install
```

XCode doesn't recognize ProfileHandle variable. I think ProfileHandle is from an older version from any of the pods.

Anyone of you know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should track from where `ProfileHandle` is coming from. Also, try running `pod update`

Comment: I did it and ProfileHandler is from no place. It's weird! pod update doesn't fix my problem